# Plucking out all hash keys that has a specific word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

How do you pluck out  a hash key that has for example

Hash 1
{sample => {apple => 1, guest_email => my_email@example.com }}

Hash 2
{guest => {email => my_email@example.com}}

Lets say I want 1 method that will pluck out the email from either of those hashes, is there any way I can that like lets say hash.get_key_match("email")

Comment: your hash key always change too???

Comment: yeah basically if im given 2 types of hash from external source so lets say i have to deal with that 2 types

Comment: A kludge: `h = {:sample => {:apple => 1, :guest_email => 'my_email@example.com' }};
h.to_s[/(?<=email=>")[^"]+/] #=> "my_email@example.com"`.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `Hash#select` to only return keypairs, matching the block:

```rb
h = { guest_email: 'some_mail', other_key: '123', apple: 1 }

h.select { |key, _value| key =~ /email/ }
#=> { guest_email: 'some_mail' }
```

Comment: This is a good start for me, how do I pluck just the value (no keys) when there's a match?

Comment: You could go for `hash.values`

Comment: hash.values.select {|key, value| key =~ /email/} returns []

Comment: `h.select { |key, _value| key =~ /email/ }.values`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
hash = { first_email: 'first_email', second_email: 'second_email' }


hash.select { |key, _value| key =~ /email/ }.map {|k, v| v}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need the deep search.
There is no method from the box.

You need use recursion for this goal.

I suspect that your issue can be solved by:

```
class Hash
  def deep_find(key, node = self)
    searchable_key = key.to_s
    matched_keys = node.keys.select { |e| e.to_s.match?(searchable_key) }
    return node[matched_keys.first] if matched_keys.any?

    node.values
        .select { |e| e.respond_to?(:deep_find) }
        .map { |e| e.deep_find(key, e) }
        .flatten.first
  end
end

h = {a_foo: {d: 4}, b: {foo: 1}}
p (h.deep_find(:foo))
# => {:d=>4}

h = {a: 2, c: {a_foo: :bar}, b: {foo: 1}}
p (h.deep_find(:foo))
# => :bar
```